# How can I get a full-sized UINavigationBar titleView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a custom control as the titleView in a UINavigationBar. When I do so, despite setting the frame and the properties that would normally assume full width, I get this:
[image]

The bright blue can be ignored as it is where I am hiding my custom control.  The issue is the narrow strips of navbar at the ends of the bar.  How can I get rid of these so my customview will stretch 100%?

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.width, kDefaultBarHeight);
UANavBarControlView *control = [[[UANavBarControlView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
control.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; 
self.navigationItem.titleView = control;
```

PS - I know I can add the view by itself instead of being attached to a navigation bar and it would be very easy to position it myself. I have my reasons for needing it to be "on" the navigation bar, and those reasons are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747991/uisearchbar-animating-of-top-of-another-uiview-besides-uinavigationbar)

Comment: You are lucky you can get that width; I have a non-full-width title view, but it still gets compressed horizontally...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Setting the titleView of your view's navigationItem will never do the trick.  Instead, you can add a subView to the navigation controller's navigationBar :

```
UIView* ctrl = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:navController.navigationBar.bounds];
ctrl.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
ctrl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[navController.navigationBar addSubview:ctrl];
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work well with navigation.  Pushing a viewcontroller on the stack leves it here.  I could remove it before the pushes and pulls, but this seems very hacky

Comment: I ended up hacking it to work by adding animations to add/remove it on viewwillappear and viewwilldissapear. A hacky solution for a hacky question I guess. I will hold off on giving you the bounty to see if a better solution appears.

Comment: That's what I did as well. As you say : hacky solution !

Comment: Have you tried subclassing UINavigationController to change the frame of the titleview internally ?  I have no idea how to do it though !

Comment: + 1, This works, but I am surprised there isn't a more straight forward way to do this yet...

Comment: As noted above, this hack becomes very obvious if you're adding/removing the subview on viewWillAppear/Disappear if you're using the iOS 7 swipe from left to navigate back from a view that's been pushed.  The solution below (overriding setFrame) lets you continue to use the nav item's titleView allowing the system to manage the alpha correctly during navigation.

Answer (score 28):

Just ran into the same problem and after a bit of thinking solved it. titleView's frame gets set by the navigationBar every time it appears.

All you have to do is subclass UIView and override `setFrame`.

Like this:

```
    - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
        [super setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 50.0)];
    }
```

Now set your sneaky new UIView as the `navigationItem.titleView` and enjoy its newfound resistance to resizing by the superview.

You don't have to set super's frame every time your frame gets set. You can just set it once and be done. If you want to support orientation changes you could probably hack that together too.

Comment: this helped me in ios5.0 when setting the title view.. Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: For anyone running into the same problem... if your titleview isn't showing, you need to override layoutSubviews, and bring the view to the front (or insert at a higher index).

Comment: +1 This is just a great solution as opposed to all the other solutions messing with layout or categories.

Comment: I think hard-coding values is a bad way to do it, I came to this code in -setFrame:

[super setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, frame.origin.y, self.superview.frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

Comment: What is this in Swift?

Answer (score 4):

The following code worded on **iOS8/iOS9/iOS10/iOS11**.

Code in swift 3

```
class TitleView: UIView {

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            super.frame = newValue.insetBy(dx: -newValue.minX, dy: 0)
        }
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        if let superview = superview {
            frame = superview.bounds
            translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        }
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        /// remove autolayout warning in iOS11
        superview?.constraints.forEach { constraint in
            if fabs(constraint.constant) == 8 {
                constraint.isActive = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: This is surprisingly fragile so be sure to use it as-is. I thought I'd get fancy and move the constraint removal to didMoveToSubview. That crashes on iOS 10!

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of ksm's answer

```
let leftOffset: CGFloat = 60
let rightOffset: CGFloat = 60

@objc override var frame: CGRect {
     didSet {
                let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - leftOffset - rightOffset
                let height: CGFloat = 44

                super.frame = CGRect(
                    x: leftOffset,
                    y: 20,
                    width: width,
                    height: height
                )
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks `@VdesmedT` for the answers , I have been using this answer to achieve a full screen size titleView in navigationbar .

But, I have just upgraded to iOS11 recently and I found that this solution did not work. And so I figured it out by another way(may seem weird). The core of the idea is not to change the titleView's size, but to change the subViews of the bar to achive the fullscreen bar affects

1. make a barView (make sure the barView width is screenSize - 12*2, 12
   is the system padding set to to titleView, you can use manual layout
   or autolayout's constraint to achive this). and then set it as
   navigation bar's titleView
2. add your components into this barView. you can align the components
   from -12 to the barView's width + 12
3. overload your barView's pointInside , to make it respondable even
   when the click happed outside the barView.

   ```
   - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
     BOOL ret = [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
     if (ret == NO)
     {
       CGRect expandRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -12, 0, -12));
       ret = CGRectContainsPoint(expandRect, point);
   }
   return ret;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -7):

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);

```
UILabel *titlelabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

titlelabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

titlelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

titlelabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

titlelabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];

titlelabel.text =@"Available Reports";

self.navigationItem.titleView = titlelabel;
```

if you want to set image then take uiimage view instead on uilable you can create any view of fully navigation bar just tell me how ur navigation look like i will send you code for that if you want i can put 6 button on navigation also

Comment: I guess you didn't even try that before posting did you ?

Comment: this only appears to work for you because you have a clear background.