# Swift: Get width of titleView in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I created a UIView which I would like to add to the NavigationBar's titleView, like so:

```
let progressBar = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 5))
progressBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.navigationItem.titleView = progressBar
```

I set the width of the UIView same as the screen's frame to make sure that it is wide enough (see first line of the code above). Then I added the UIView to the NavigationBar (see line 3).

Since the available space within NavigationBar is smaller than `self.view.frame.width`, my UIView (progressBar) gets shrunk down to fit the width of the NavigationBar. Hence, the width of my UIView (progressBar) is now smaller than `self.view.frame.width`.

How can I get the new size of the UIView within the NavigationBar?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you can get full size navigation bar 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3778236/3976183

Comment: if let width = self.navigationItem.titleView?.frame.size.width {
        print(width)
}